# How to fix error in GridLayout/GridBagConstraints?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

Why `GridLayot` not working in Swing Java?

I need to place element at concrete cell, but they placing wrong [(picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEejJ.png)

How to place elements to concrete cell in Java Swing with grid layout?

My code:

```java
package com.KvaksManYT;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame {
    public GUI() {
        super("Test");
        setBounds(100, 100, 250, 100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container container = this.getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2, 2, 2));
        container.add(but1, onPosition(1, 2));
        container.add(but2, onPosition(2, 2));
        container.add(but3, onPosition(1, 1));
        container.add(but4, onPosition(2, 1));
    }

    private JButton but1 = new JButton("Press 1");
    private JButton but2 = new JButton("Press 2");
    private JButton but3 = new JButton("Press 3");
    private JButton but4 = new JButton("Press 4");

    private GridBagConstraints onPosition(int x, int y) {
        GridBagConstraints layConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        layConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        layConstraints.gridx = x;
        layConstraints.gridy = y;
        return layConstraints;
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson thank's you, pls write this as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GridBagConstraints` is used for [Grid **Bag** Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html), rather than [Grid Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridLayout.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have to start counting at 0 too:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {
    public GUI() {
        super("Test");
        setBounds(100, 100, 250, 100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        GridBagConstraints layConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        layConstraints.fill  = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        layConstraints.insets = new Insets(3, 2, 2, 2);

        Container container = this.getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        container.add(but1, onPosition(0, 1, layConstraints));
        container.add(but2, onPosition(1, 1, layConstraints));
        container.add(but3, onPosition(0, 0, layConstraints));
        container.add(but4, onPosition(1, 0, layConstraints));

    }
```